# JavaVM.framework deleted and not anymore able to install Java

Tags: macos, java

`/System/Library/Framework/JavaVM.framework` and `/System/Library/Java` have been deleted from my disk. I thought of making things back to normal by running the last Apple Java update ([Java for OS X Lion 2012-003 as of this writing](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1515)) but unfortunately I'm facing the following error message:

```
A newer version of this package is already installed.
```

I still have java from oracle but I'd like to have the official one as well.

Any idea how I could get over this error message and proceed the install?

Comment: How did that happen?

Comment: I had the same exact problem. This is the apple directory for the OS X related Java installation files and prerequisites. I ended up installing OS X java package from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US. After doing that installing newer versions of Java was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up to reinstall Lion using Recovery. Data/Applications are kept even no need of a backup and then Java install prompted again on 1st usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would install the [Oracle Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) as it is a complete separate install, and would work even if you deleted its parts. Also Apple have stopped doing new versions of Java and left this to Oracle as occurs on other OSs.